# How do you understand the Moy-Prasad filtration of G_2?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, buildings

Starting on page 44 of [this paper](https://www2.bc.edu/~reederma/Epipelagic.pdf) of Reeder and Yu, the authors describe the first graded piece of the Moy-Prasad filtration on $G_2$ at a certain point (in this case it's $GL_2$ of the residue field), and then go on to describe the representation on the second piece of the filtration (in this case its the action on binary cubics plus the determinant).

I assume that these descriptions were not obtained by explicitly writing down a matrix group model of $G_2$. I would like to know how one can obtain this explicit description in the case of $G_2$, and how to go about explicitly understanding the gradeds of the Moy-Prasad filtration in general, if a general discussion is possible.

Comment: It's probably best to start by asking Reeder and/or Yu directly.    By the way, the published paper is here: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3164986

Comment: My way of doing this: The usual picture of the root system of $G_2$ has five rows (the rows have 1,4,2,4,1 roots, respectively). The "certain point'' is characterized by that a root on the n-th row takes value $\equiv n/3$ mod $\mathbb{Z}$, thus the roots appearing in the reductive quotient are those in the 3rd row, giving your $GL_2$ (the way these roots appear in the character lattice should tell you it's not $SL_2\times\mathbb{G}_m$ or so). For the depth-$(1/3)$ quotient, you get the 1st and the 4th row, which gives the binary cubics and trivial + appropriate twists by determinant.

Comment: Allow me to also put some general murmuring. The way I learned to compute reductive quotients is reading Tits' Corvallis article, which for me is the best reference (but many people better than me might object). For other quotients in the Moy-Prasad filtration, well, I also learn it essentially from Corvallis (and of course, the Moy-Prasad paper). Note that this time you only need to compute it for the Lie algebra.